# help me identify this plant?

Tags: identification

It is a creeper, grows very fast, orange color flowers, leaves like little bit sticky paper.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Looks very much like cucumber to me. https://www.google.com/search?q=cucumber+plant&tbm=isch

Comment: a member of the curcurbit family for sure, cucumber, squash, zucchini

Comment: Dont think it's a cucumber plant because you only have one flower on each leaf joint and you clearly have three in your picture.
As to the plants origins jury's still out!!!